# Python to C converter / interpreter

Tags: python, c, converters

What are various tools to convert Python scripts to C. I am mainly looking at speed of such tools/converter/interpreter.

Thanks,
-J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cython is what you are looking for http://www.cython.org/

Comment: sounds interesting. thanks. !

Comment: +1, interesting, I'd missed that you could do this, it seems there is more information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710441/call-cython-function-from-c

Comment: he said "python". Cython is not python.

Answer (score 3):

Mark Dufour's [Shedskin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) is an interesting alternative, that can parse a large subset of python, and translate it to C++. The project also has a really good [blog](http://shed-skin.blogspot.com.au/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pypy to translate a subset of Python language to C](http://doc.pypy.org/en/release-2.4.x/translation.html).

Comment: Subset *means* subset. Very little useful Python code will pass as RPython unmodified, and 99% will become very ugly (compared to full Python) when converted to RPython. RPython is a quite different programming language that Python interpreters happen to accept.