# Undefined symbol (linking .so C and Cython Code)

Tags: cython

*Since I made some progress, I changed the title and made a second edit describing my new problem. You may choose to ignore Edit1*

I have been trying to run python code from C code. And for this purpose I have been using Cython.

The semantics of my system is such that there is a binary (whos source I can not access) that calls a C function defined in a file (source is accessible) and within this function I need to call python functions, do some processing and return the result to binary.

To achieve this purpose, there are two approaches that I came across:

1. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ext/callingPython.html ===> This approach suggests to have the python callback function passed to the C side, so that the callback is called as necessary, but this doesn't work for me as I don't have access to the binary's source (which is used to run the entire system)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721123/1126425 ==> I have tried this approach and I get this error when the cython function is called:
   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   [Switching to Thread 0xb47deb70 (LWP 2065)]
   0x007fd38a in PySys_GetObject () from /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
3. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497?page=0,0 ==> This is in fact the basis for cython's functionality but again when I use the examples described there, I get errors similar to 2.

I have no idea how to resolve these errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

**Edit1:**
here is a simple scenario that reflects situation:

---

### external.c

```
#include <external.h>

int callback(int param1,int param2)//Function that the binary calls
{
    /*SomeTasks*/
    cython_func();//Function defined in the following .pyx file
    /*SomeTasks*/
}
```

---

### cython_file.pyx

```
cdef void cython_function():
    print "Do Nothing!"
```

I am linking the shared library file created by cython with the library generated by compiling the above C code and then that library is used by the binary...

**Edit2:**
The segmentation fault goes away when I added Py_Initialize(); before calling cython_function(). But now I am getting the undefined symbol error as :  symbol lookup error: lib_c_code.so: undefined symbol: cython_function

Here lib_c_code.so is the shared library created out of the external.c file above. I have tried including the .h file created by the cython compiler in external.c but it still didn't work out.. Here is how I am compiling lib_c_code.so:

```
gcc -shared -dynlib -lm -W1 -o lib_c_code.so $(OBJDIR)/*.o -lc -lm -lpy_code
```

and the libpy_code.so is the shared object file that was created out of the cython_file.pyx file as:

```
cython cython_file.pyx -o cython_file.c
gcc $(IFLAGS) -I/usr/include/python2.6 -fPIC -shared cython_file.c -lpython2.6 -lm -o libpy_code.so
```

Also, I can see the symbol cython_function in the lib_c_code.so file when I do : nm -g lib_c_code.so..
Any ideas please?

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: @user946850 I can not post the code ... but I have updated the post with an example...

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess here that there's a callback registration function to which you can pass the function pointer, in which case you can simply forego the C file and define a cdef function directly in your Cython code, and pass that with the callback registration function. Use `with gil` in case you manipulate any Python objects in it.

```
cdef extern from "external.h":
    ctypedef int (*Cb_Func)(int param1, int param2)
    void register_callback(Cb_Func func)

cdef int my_callback(int param1,int param2) with gil:
    <implementation>

register_callback(my_callback)
```

This is also explained in the Cython user manual here: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html